# boot.ci() in R gives unreasonable confidence intervals for log-normal data set

Tags: r

So, here is the function that outputs the mean for log-normal data:

```
 boot_mean <- function(data, ind){
     exp(base::mean(data[ind])+var(data[ind])/2)
    }
```

If I apply `boot.ci(boot())` functions to log-normal data, I get unreasonable confidence intervals:

```
CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = boot(rlnorm(n, meanlog = 1, sdlog = 0.5), 
    statistic = boot_mean, R = 100))

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   (  1.22, 111.72 )   (-13.43,  98.39 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 27.45, 139.28 )   ( 26.77, 137.85 )
```

I suppose, there is something wrong with the boot_mean function, maybe someone sees the error?

EDIT:
Here is the edited statistic function:

```
boot_mean <- function(data, ind){
    ld <- log(data[ind])
    exp(base::mean(ld)+var(ld)/2)
  }
```

But using this function the outputted confidence intervals lie around 3:

```
CALL : 
boot.ci(boot.out = boot(rlnorm(n, meanlog = 1, sdlog = 0.5), 
    statistic = boot_mean, R = 100))

Intervals : 
Level      Normal              Basic         
95%   ( 2.730,  3.507 )   ( 2.743,  3.537 )  

Level     Percentile            BCa          
95%   ( 2.694,  3.488 )   ( 2.728,  3.499 )
```

Comment: Can you give us a [mcve] please, i.e. the *complete* code that you used? (We could probably reconstruct it but it's easier if you just provide it ...)

Comment: It's not generally good practice to edit your question to incorporate answers - it makes the answers redundant and/or makes things confusing for later readers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want

```r
boot_mean <- function(data, ind) {
   ld <- log(data[ind])
   exp(base::mean(ld)+var(ld)/2)
}
```

That is, we want `exp(mean(x) + var(x)/2)` where the `x` is *on the log scale* ...

Comment: Thanks, now the confidence intervals are more reasonable, but I guess the exp() is unnecessary because it gives out the statistic to be around 3? Should I just leave it as mean(ld) + var(ld)/2 ?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  If you want to compute confidence intervals on the (arithmetic) mean of the samples, then you need `exp()`.  If you  want CIs on the log of the arithmetic mean, then you don't ...

Comment: But then the boot.ci() function outputs incorrect confidence intervals. If mu = 1, the confidence intervals for all bootstrap methods are around 3, when it should be around 1.

Comment: I understand that first we took a logarithm, so it should be then applied to exp(), but for some reason the statistic comes out closer to 3 than 1.

Comment: You may be confused about the definition/parameterization of the log-normal. `meanlog` refers the mean of the distribution *on the log scale*. We expect that mean(rlnorm(., meanlog=1, sdlog=0.5)) is `exp(1+0.5^2/2)` = 3.0802 ...